# How to avoid dynamically allocating memory to save time?

Tags: c, string, performance, malloc

I have a function which is called many times in my project:

```
void foo(int bar)
{  
    char arr[1024];
    //...do some operation on arr according to value of bar  
}
```

Now, in some rare cases, I am getting a segmentation fault when the value of `bar` is large. I need to increase the size of `arr`, whose size I can know from value of `bar`.

The obvious solution seems to dynamically allocate memory for `arr` depending on size of `bar`. However, this function is called very frequently, and I think allocating memory each time can decrease performance.

What should be my strategy to tackle this?

Comment: `I think allocating memory each time can decrease performance` Thinking it will, and knowing it does are two different things. I suggest you go the `malloc` route and worry about performance only when it starts to affect whatever your program does.

Comment: Also consider using alloca if the largest possible array size will fit comfortably on the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Allocate dynamically, but reuse the buffer. So `foo` will also get a buffer as a parameter from the calling function (if called from the same function in a loop, for example. I wouldn't pass the buffer all over the program if `foo` is called from 100 different places). This way, you only have to allocate once the buffer needs to be increased.
2. Declare a large local array as you do now, but make sure it's large enough before using it. If not, dynamically allocate one on the heap. Assuming the local array is large enough for most cases, you'll only allocate on the heap on rare occasions.

Edit:

Regarding #2, @David Heffernan got heat for suggesting the same option, as it might be a complication of the code. I don't think the following is very complicated:

```
void foo(int bar)
{
    char localArr[1024];
    char* arr = localArr;
    if (sizeNeeded > 1024)
        arr = malloc(sizeNeeded);

    // ... use arr in logic ...

    if (arr != localArr)
        free(arr);
}
```

I've used similar code in some frequently invoked callback where I couldn't reuse the buffer, and eliminating the malloc on most cases has definitely improved performance. Whether that's the best solution for the OP I really don't know.

Answer (score 4):

If heap allocation performance is an issue then you can retain the stack allocated buffer for when bar<1024, but use a heap allocated buffer otherwise.

I would recommend profiling your app to see if using a heap allocation is actually discernibly slower than the constant sized array on the stack. Modern heaps peform very well. Don't optimise your code in a way that obfuscates it unless there is a significant benefit.

Comment: Using both a stack and heap allocated buffer seems like an unnecessary complication, not to mention that you end up spending stack space even for the case where data is allocated on the heap. Wouldn't it be better to just share the buffer between invocations wherever possible?

Comment: @michael maybe, depends on what is inside foo and how it is called. We don't know any of that. This feels like premature optimisation though.

Comment: @Michael, I think this option is neither a significant complication nor unnecessary, at least on some cases. Please see my answer, in which I've suggested the same option (as well as the option you suggest...)

Answer (score 3):

```
void foo(int bar) {
    char arr[1024];
    // ...
}
```

First you need to resolve run-time errors and then go for performance issues. With the information you given, there is no relation between `bar` and the sizeof the array `arr`. You are getting segmentation faults probably because you are trying to access locations not from **0 to 1023**. If what you want is array of `bar` length, then `malloc` it and `free` it when you no longer need it.

Comment: It'd be more efficient to simply do `char arr[bar];` if you wanted to go that route. If you don't need to access the memory outside of the function stack allocation and cleanup is going to be faster.

Comment: @Brain Roach - I understand `C99` supports variable length arrays. But I didn't suggest it because the OP might think it works for C++ too. It's good to think array size should always be a **compile time constant** and play accordingly.

Comment: Erm, that's not a variable length array ... it's an array created on the stack within a function. That being said, the question doesn't provide enough detail to actually be answered and we're all just guessing as to that he's *doing* with the array.

Comment: @brian yes it is a VLA since bar is not constant! And you risk stack overflow.

Comment: Bizarre, never heard it called that. But yes, given a sufficient size you could blow out the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You should stick with allocating memory, if there is a possibility for bar to be greater than 1024. Besides, it may not be such a good idea to allocate 1kb in the stack, specially if your function may be called recursively (which I guess it doesn't). Keep around the allocations from previous calls, or use a pool of allocated buffers, in order to avoid freeing and reallocating memory if a previous allocation is enough. Prepare to face trouble on concurrent calls to foo.

Answer (score 1):

Allow the user to supply the buffer, so that, if this function is invoked in a loop, the user can construct the buffer once (before the loop) and pass the same buffer in on each iteration. I.e., use:

```
 // Preconditions:
 //     buffer_ptr MUST NOT be NULL.
 //     buffer_len_ptr MUST NOT be NULL.
 //
 // Parameters:
 //     bar -- Whatever bar does
 //     buffer_ptr -- Points to a pointer to a malloc-allocated buffer.
 //     buffer_len_ptr -- Points to a variable indicating the size of *buffer_ptr
 //
 // Side-Effects:
 //     May expand the buffer, causing *buffer_ptr to point to a new, larger
 //     buffer, in which case *buffer_len_ptr will have the new size. 
 //
 void foo(int bar, char** buffer_ptr, size_t* buffer_len_ptr);
```

Comment: If foo is called many times this results in unacceptable obfuscation at each call site

Comment: It would be acceptable to define a helper function that uses a thread-specific buffer, so that each call site does not need to pass its own buffer explicitly.

Comment: If foo is called from many places this results in unacceptable
obfuscation at each call site

Comment: @David Hefferman, agreed, assuming that you were to use the same buffer at each call site. Again, though, you could potentially create a wrapper for this function that invokes it with a thread-specific buffer (so that the call site does not need to pass the buffer explicitly). However, I'm much more for being explicit even if it is a tad ugly; too much magic can lead to unanticipated results.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

```
void foo_inner(size_t bar, char arr[bar]);
```

Declaring `arr` as array in the prototype is only cosmetics but clearly shows your intentions.
(Another possibility would be to have `char arr[static 1]` to force it to be a non-null pointer.)

Then I would write a macro for the use case where the caller doesn't have an array at hand

```
#define foo(BAR)              \
if (1) {                      \
  size_t foo_bar = BAR;       \
  char foo_arr[foo_bar];      \
  foo_inner(foo_bar, foo_arr);\
} else (void)0
```

or

```
#define foo(BAR)                          \
if (1) {                                  \
  size_t foo_bar = BAR;                   \
  char * foo_arr = malloc(foo_bar);       \
  if(foo_arr) foo_inner(foo_bar, foo_arr);\
  free(foo_arr);                          \
} else (void)0
```

depending if you think VLA are safe for you or not in your situation.

On the call site you then can choose to call `foo` in places where you are sure it will not hurt too much, and optimize calls inside loops or so by allocating a buffer beforehand.